# Handle duplicate numbers in kth smallest partition

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I've gotten my partition algorithm and the ksmall recursion methods to compute (almost) completely... I'm just running into a case where (I believe) my partition algorithm isn't handling duplicate numbers in the randomly given array. Any other array and my output works perfectly.

The recursion and partition checks to place all numbers less than the pivot on the left, and all numbers greater than the pivot, on the right.

How can I handle duplicate numbers in the random array?

**Here's my code:**

```
private static int partition(int[] theArray, int first, int last) {
    // Returns the index of the pivot element after partitioning
    // theArray[first..last]

    int p = theArray[first]; // use the first item of the array as the pivot (p)
    int lastS1 = first; // set S1 and S2 to empty
    int lastS2 = theArray.length-1;

    while (lastS1 < lastS2) {
        for (; theArray[lastS1] < p; lastS1++) ;

        for (; theArray[lastS2] > p && lastS2 > 0; lastS2--) ;
        if (lastS1 < lastS2)
            swap(theArray, lastS1, lastS2);
    }
    swap(theArray, lastS1, lastS2);
    return lastS2;
}
public static int kSmall(int k, int[] anArray, int first, int last) {
    int pivotIndex = partition(anArray, first, last);
    int p = anArray[pivotIndex]; // p is the pivot



        if (pivotIndex == k - 1)

            return anArray[pivotIndex];
    if (p > anArray[k - 1])

        return kSmall(k, anArray, first, pivotIndex - 1);

    return kSmall(k, anArray, pivotIndex + 1, last);
```

**Editing in some examples with a deeper explanation:**

Here are some examples of **Successful** runs:

```
array = [13 | 29 | 53 | 49 | 68 | 12 | 72 | 47 | 80 | 89]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Please  enter an integer k, 1<=k<=10, or 'R' to refill the array: 
1
Kth smallest is: 12
With K as: 1
```

and...

```
array = [60 | 45 | 27 | 20 | 4 | 80 | 75 | 59 | 78 | 41]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Please  enter an integer k, 1<=k<=10, or 'R' to refill the array: 
1
Kth smallest is: 4
With K as: 1
```

An **Unsuccessful** run:

```
array = [68 | 77 | 32 | 54 | 30 | 83 | 68 | 76 | 64 | 30]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Please  enter an integer k, 1<=k<=10, or 'R' to refill the array: 
5
```

In this array, there are two '30' integers, and I'm guessing the program isn't moving over to the next one for some reason.

*Thank you for any assistance you can provide!*

Comment: The `last` parameter of `partition` isn't referenced.

Comment: What do you expect to be output of last example?

Comment: @hgminh the output should be the 5th smallest number. Which would be 64 I believe.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, about the `partition` function:

- As @teppic mentioned, this function is supposed to do the partition in `theArray[first..last]`. Therefore, `last` should be assigned to `lastS2`.
- Your implementation also fails when all the array is the same. In that case, `lastS1` and `lastS2` never change which leads to infinite loop. I suggest you check out some other implementation of `partition` (e.g. [this one](https://visualgo.net/en/sorting) - select quick sort, there are pseudo code in bottom right section).

About `kSmall` function, your condition `p > anArray[k - 1]` is not correct. The idea is that after you do the partition, separate the array into 2 parts at `pivotIndex`. The first part contains `pivotIndex - 1` smallest elements and the second part contains `arraySize - pivotIndex` biggest elements. Using that information, you can decide which part the k-smallest element falls into:

```
if (pivotIndex == k - 1)
    return a[k - 1];
else if (pivotIndex > k - 1)
    return kSmall(k, a, first, pivotIndex - 1);
else
    return kSmall(k, a, pivotIndex + 1, last);
```

Comment: This was really useful information, but I'm not entirely sure how to implement that quick sort partition.